# Pandas aggregation - calculations between columns

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this dataframe:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df_agg = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                              'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                       'C' : np.random.choice(2, 8)})
```

I'd like to calculate following columns grouped by `A`:

- Number of elements
- Number of True in `C`
- Percentage of True in `C`
- Number of False in `C`
- Percentage of False in `C`

First three elements are simple using aggregations:

```
aggregations = {
    'C': {
        'Number of elements': 'count',
        'Number of True':sum,
        'Percentage of True': 'mean'
    }
}
df_tab = df_agg.groupby('A').agg(aggregations)
print df_tab
```

And he output:

```
                     C                                  
    Number of elements Number of True Percentage of True
A                                                       
bar                  3              2           0.666667
foo                  5              4           0.800000
```

However I dont know how, in the same aggregation, calculate columns which are combination of other columns - number and percentage of False.

As a workaround, I can do this:

```
df_tab = df_tab['C'] #flatten
df_tab['Number of False'] = df_tab['Number of elements'] - df_tab['Number of True']
df_tab['Percentage of False'] = 1 - df_tab['Percentage of True']
```

Which will yield what I want, but I am wondering how to do it all at once.

```
     Number of elements  Number of True  Percentage of True  Number of False  Percentage of False
A                                                                                                
bar                   3               2            0.666667                1             0.333333
foo                   5               4            0.800000                1             0.200000
```

Comment: I think your choices are 1) define secondary columns such as "number of false" explicitly and 2) create a secondary dataframe and append that to `df_tab`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the following quesiton from [that comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720579/pandas-aggregation-calculations-between-columns/41720752#comment70636235_41720752):

> Assuming I need more complex calculations and refer to other columns.
>   Is there a way how to refer to a column in, for example, lambda
>   function

Assuming we have have the following DF:

```
In [62]: %paste
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'A': {0: 'foo',
  1: 'bar',
  2: 'foo',
  3: 'bar',
  4: 'foo',
  5: 'bar',
  6: 'foo',
  7: 'foo'},
 'C': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1},
 'X': {0: 0.56804456109393231,
  1: 0.92559663829266103,
  2: 0.071036058197886942,
  3: 0.087129299701540708,
  4: 0.020218397440325719,
  5: 0.832619845547938,
  6: 0.77815675094985048,
  7: 0.87001214824681916}})
## -- End pasted text --

In [63]: df
Out[63]:
     A  C         X
0  foo  0  0.568045
1  bar  1  0.925597
2  foo  1  0.071036
3  bar  0  0.087129
4  foo  1  0.020218
5  bar  1  0.832620
6  foo  1  0.778157
7  foo  1  0.870012
```

**Solution:**

[groupby.GroupBy.apply()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) gives us access to all columns in the grouped chunk of DF:

```
In [78]: %paste
def f(grp):
    return pd.DataFrame({
                'Number of elements':len(grp),
                'Number of True': grp['C'].sum(),
                'Percentage of True': grp['C'].mean(),
                'XXX': grp['C'].mean() / grp['X'].sum()},  # <--- here we access different columns...
                index=[grp.name])
## -- End pasted text --

In [79]: df.groupby('A', as_index=False).apply(f)
Out[79]:
       Number of True  Number of elements  Percentage of True       XXX
0 bar               2                   3            0.666667  0.361269
1 foo               4                   5            0.800000  0.346700
```

Comment: is there a way to add cumulative sum as a column in here? thanks

Answer (score 3):

you can use lambda functions:

```
In [43]: aggregations = {
    ...:     'C': {
    ...:         'Number of elements': 'count',
    ...:         'Number of True':sum,
    ...:         'Percentage of True': 'mean',
    ...:         'Number of False': lambda x: len(x) - np.count_nonzero(x),
    ...:         'Percentage of False': lambda x: 1 - x.mean()
    ...:     }
    ...: }
    ...:
    ...: df_agg.groupby('A').agg(aggregations)
    ...:
Out[43]:
                  C
    Number of False Percentage of False Number of True Number of elements Percentage of True
A
bar               1            0.333333              2                  3           0.666667
foo               1            0.200000              4                  5           0.800000
```

Comment: I like this, good idea. In this particular case it will work. But assuming I need more complex calculations and refer to other columns. Is there a way how to refer to a column in, for example, lambda function?

Comment: @HonzaB, it's going to be tricky, as AFAIK `.agg()` will be applied separateley to single columns

Comment: @HonzaB, can you make an example where you would need to access another columns ?

Comment: Hm, I was thinking the same. But I just noticed - The columns in your output `Percentage of False` and `Percentage of True` are same. Moreover, I get 0 when I run your code. Could you have a look at it?

Comment: @HonzaB, sure, there was a mistake for the `Percentage of False` calculation

Comment: Nice, thx! Well so far I have only this example and thinking it would be nice to know.

Comment: @HonzaB, i've added [yet another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41721867/5741205) where i tried to answer your question: `assuming I need more complex calculations and refer to other columns. Is there a way how to refer to a column in, for example, lambda function`